# Increasing/Altering Matlab-Arduino analogRead() sampling rate

Tags: matlab, time, arduino, sampling, rate

I have been controlling Arduino from Matlab using ArduinoIO-Matlab interface. My current setup is I have 3 EMG Muscle Sensors (from Advancer Technologies) are connected to the Arduino at analog pin 1,2, and 3. Arduino is connected to Matlab. I am trying to collect data from these three pins simultaneously and store them in an matrix size 1000x3. My issue is the rate at which Matlab is sampling from the analog pin. It takes about 25 seconds to collect 1000 readings from the 3 pins simultaneously. I know arduino itself samples at a higher rate. Below is my code. How do I alter this to get a sampling rate of about like 1000 samples in 10 seconds ?

```
ar = arduino('COM3');

ax = zeros(1000,3);

for ai = 1:1000
    ax(ai,:) = [ar.analogRead(1) ar.analogRead(2) ar.analogRead(3)];
end

delete(ar);
```

This is the time taken by the above code (profile viewer):

```
  time     calls  line
< 0.01       1    3 ax = zeros(1000,3); 
                  4 
< 0.01       1    5 for ai = 1:1000 
 25.07    1000    6     ax(ai,:) = [ar.analogRead(1) ar.analogRead(2) ar.analogRead(3)]; 
          1000    7 end 
                  8 
  1.24       1    9 delete(ar);
```

Please let me know if there is something else that I need to clarify.
Thanks :D`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the arduino c++ code (.pde file).
In this code you should sample the signal as you prefer (1000 for example) and then transfer the sampled data to matlab using serial.writeln() method.

This will give you a sampling rate of ~3KHz (depending on alot of factors)...

Comment: Hi Muhammad. Can you please clarify a little further? Where exactly and how in the "adiosrv.pde" arduino code do I have to set rate. I was looking at the adiosrv.pde but couldn't understand or find where I had to do the modification.

Comment: I worked with the simple IO scheme (adiosrv.pde).The analog reading is performed using "case 30" in the code (starts @217). Instead of requesting an input from arduino, reading one input and sending it to Matlab using serial write, i did the following:
for(int i=0;i<1000;++i)
Serial.println(analogRead(pin));
You also need to modify the analogRead method in matlab code:
for i=1:1000
signal(i) = fscanf(a.ser,"%d");
end
A better way to do the sampling is to sample the whole signal and then send it back to Matlab via serial, actually that didn't worked out for me (what I have is satisfactory...)

Comment: Ok. Btw sorry for the late response. My exams were up so I wasn't able to try this. Now Case 30 in the adiosrv.pde has 
if (val>96 && val<113) {
        pin=val-97;                
        agv=analogRead(pin);       
 Serial.println(agv);      
      }
      s=-1;  
      break; 
What part of this should I append ? 
Also this is only for when I need to take a fixed size of data. For the purpose of real time continuous data acquisition, what should be done ?

Comment: agv=analogRead(pin); Serial.println(agv); should be replaced by:
for(int i=0;i<1000;++i) 
{ 
delay(1/fs);
ag_vec[i]=analogRead(pin);
Serial.println(ag_vec[i]);
}
by changing fs you can increase/decrease the sampling rate. note that if you read from multiple pins you need to add a small delay so there will be no cross-talk between the pins.

Comment: Ok today I tried to implement what you have suggested. I did the replacement in case 30 (had to initialize ag_vec). Now my matlab code is:   ar = arduino('COM3');
ax = zeros(1000,3);

for i=1:1000 
    signal(i) = fscanf(ar.ser,'%d');
end
delete(ar);        .
I get this when I run the above code from matlab:
"No appropriate method, property, or field ser for class
arduino.

Error in buffer (line 6)
    signal(i) = fscanf(ar.ser,'%d');"
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The following very probably explains the result that you are seeing and why you need to do something like what Muhammad's answer suggests. While this reason was implied by his answer it was not spelt out so that others can avoid the 'trap'.

I do not have access to the underlying code and systems needed to check this answer with certainty. This answer is based on "typical methods" and has a modest chance of being sheer poppycock [tm], but the exact fit between observation and standard methods suggests this is what is happening. A very little delving by someone with the requisite system to hand will demonstrate if this is correct.

When data is sent one data sample at a time you incur a per-sample overhead significantly in excess of the time taken to just transfer the raw data.

You say it takes 25 seconds to transfer 3000 samples.
The time per sample = 25/3000 = 8.333 ms per sample.

Assume a 9600 baud data transfer rate.
The default communications speed is liable to but 9600 baud. This can be checked but the result suggests that this may be correct and making slightly different assumptions provides an equally good explanation.

Serial coms usually uses N81 format = 1 start bit, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit per 8 bit byte.
So 1 bit takes 1/9600 s
and 10 bits take 10/9600 = 1.042 mS
And sample time / byte time
= 8.333 / 1.042 = 7.997 word times.
In fact if you do the calculations without rounding or truncation, ie
25 / 3000 x 9600/10 = 8.000.... .
ie your transfer is taking EXACTLY 8 x 9600 baud word times per sample.
Equally, this is exactly 4 x 4800 baud or 2 x 2400 baud transfer times.

I have not examined the format used but imagine that to work with the PC monitor program the basic serial routine may use
2 x data bytes  + CR + LF = 4 bytes.
That assumes a 16 bit variable sent as 2 x 8 bit binary words.
More likely = either
- 16 bits sent as 4 x ASCII characters or
- 24 bits sent as 6 x ASCII characters.

In the absence of suitably deep delving, the use of 6 ASCII words and a CR + LF at 9600 baud provides such a good fit using typical parameters that Occam probably opines that this is the best starting point. Regardless of whether the total requirement is 8 or 4 or 2 bytes, the somewhat serendipitous exact match between your observed data rate and standard baud rates suggests that this provides the basic reason for what you see.

Looking at the code will rapidly show what baud rate, data length and packing is used.